# 3-way cross tab in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to create a 3 way cross tab like this:

[image: 3 way cross tab]

In SQL server? Is so whats the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the CUBE and ROLLUP functions - they will do the data summarisation for you. Then to sort out the presentation you can delve into the world-of-pain that is the PIVOT operator, or do it in your UI.

Comment: thanks, I've done a bit of research and found this article when helped solve the problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/09/27/aggregation-with-cube.aspx